# How do you reconcile an airline flight number with an ADS-B record, is this possible?

Tags: ads-b, call-sign

If you go look at arriving flights at an airport, you'll see something like "American Airlines Flight 224."

How do you cross reference that ADS-B flight data?  Is this possible?  Seems like there's some information in the "Call" field but it's not enough to match up the flights.

Comment: If you can get the tail number (N-Number), you can look up the aircraft registration to get the Mode-S code. It isn't clear to me what "ADS-B" data you are talking about? Where do you get the ADS-B data from?

Comment: The Aircraft Identification Field (ACID) has the flight ID which can be correlated to the flight number. You have to have a lookup table that is up to date. I think there are various website that maintain such a table.

Comment: @RonBeyer i'm getting data from http://www.adsbexchange.com/ and I'm trying to cross reference ads-b data to flight numbers published by airlines.

Comment: @DeltaLima here's a data sample from ADS-B, I don't see any aircraft id field, is "Call" what you're referring to? https://gist.github.com/kevinchugh/d6af1f736f33351e1820fb4d8e52bf5c

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes the ACID is called 'Call' there. You can use that for looking up the flight number.

Comment: UAL1001 *is* the flight number. It's the number for a regularly scheduled flight from Quito, Ecuador to Houston, Texas.